# Prop value undefined when passed in as an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following component where when I pass in a header value as prop, it works fine.
But due to conventions internally, I need to pass it within a data block as follow:

Instead of:

```
header: React.ReactNode;
```

Pass in as:

```
data: {
    header: React.ReactNode;
}
```

But when I pass it in as a data object, getting an error saying my **header** value is undefined. 
Why?

This is MyComponent

```
interface Props {
  data: {
    header: React.ReactNode;
  },
  // header: React.ReactNode; // works
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const MyComponent = ({
  data: { header } // header is undefined 
  // header, // works
}: Props): React.ReactElement => {

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>{header}</div>
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

This is how I pass in the data value as props.

```
<MyComponent
    data={{
        header: 'test header'
    }}
  >
    <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  </MyComponent>
```

if I uncomment the header prop above and do the following, works fine.

```
  <MyComponent header='test header'>
    <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  </MyComponent>
```

Using Docz to test this out locally. My mdx file.

```
---
menu: Menu
name: My Component
---

import { Playground } from "docz";

<Version pkg={require("../package.json")} />

## Test

<Playground>
  <MyComponent
    data={{
        header: 'test'
    }}
  >
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. .
    </div>
  </MyComponent>
</Playground>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing one pair of curly braces when you send the props?

Comment: That should be fine, have you a running snippet showing this not working.?

Comment: Is there another instance of `MyComponent` that doesn't set `data`? Is this your real code or are you setting `data` differently in your real code?

Comment: @sava128: That would be incorrect. One set is to denote an attribute value that needs to be interpreted as JavaScript, the other set is to denote an object literal. Both are necessary.

Comment: @Keith Don't have a script. Using docz to test this out where I am getting the errors. Added my mdx file above if it helps.

Comment: @FelixKling For testing I have removed a lot of my code and condensed to just this. One of those div is another component although the header undefined happens right from start thus don't think anything to do with that component. Otherwise, difference is my component name. Even the prop key in use is data too.

Comment: @FelixKling When I do not use data, works fine where I pass in header directly.

Comment: @karvai the code as it is written here seems to work fine, as can be seen in this code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-goldberg-zvlx9?file=/src/App.tsx. I suspect your problem lies elsewhere in your project.